# Using multiple versions of libyaml with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rvm

I'm using RVM on OSX Mountain Lion to manage my various Ruby installations, of which I have both the 32- and 64-bit versions of 1.9.3.  The problem I'm running into is that the 32-bit and 64-bit Ruby installations require different installations of libyaml, but they both look for libyaml in the same location (~/.rvm/usr).  So installing the 32-bit libyaml causes errors when running the 64-bit Ruby, and vice versa.

Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to know the params to build libyaml as fat binary for both platforms - then the single location could be used for both ... if you find the params for it then [open a ticket for rvm](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/new) to respect following flags `--32`/`--64`/`--universal` for `rvm pkg install ...`

Comment: do you know if an issue was ever submitted for this and fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Homebrew:

```
brew install --universal libyaml
```

Then I created a symbolic link so rvm would use the right libyaml:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4 ~/.rvm/usr
```

This got me up and running.

Comment: be careful with this setup, anything that will be installed with `rvm pkg install ...` will go to  /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4 including things like `openssl` - this might get confusing at some point. Also  ~/.rvm/usr is rvm managed path and right now your fix might work but if detection of libyaml changes rvm might overwrite your libyaml installation in there.

Comment: Good point.  My fix is definitely not a good long-term solution.